# How to fetch even and odd values from core data using Predicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I want to fetch even and odd values from my core data entity, please look into below code and correct, because its crashing the app.

```
        NSPredicate *predicate;
        if ([leadFilter.rank isEqualToString:@"Even"]) {
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(street%2) = 0"];
        }
        else
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"street%2 != 0)"];
        [predicateArray addObject:predicate];
```

**Its saying unable to parse street%2=0.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this directly in Core Data, but the syntax is a little hairy. To fetch only values of `street` that are even, set up your fetch like this:

```
NSExpression *evenOddExpression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"modulus:by:(%K,2)", @"street"];

NSFetchRequest *evenOddFetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ENTITY_NAME"];

NSExpression *zeroExpression = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:@0];
NSPredicate *evenOnly = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:evenOddExpression rightExpression:zeroExpression modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier type:NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType options:0];
evenOddFetch.predicate = evenOnly;
```

The result will be whichever managed object have an even value of `street`.

**Update**: Made simpler after Marcus pointed out that `NSDictionaryResultType` wasn't actually needed.

Comment: Yes Tom your answer is also right it solved my problem after modifying it a bit, Thanks for your valuable time and knowledge share.

Comment: Why is a `NSDictionaryResultType` required?

Comment: ... and you can short circuit the hairy syntax: `NSPredicate *evenOnly = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"modulus:by:(street,2) == 0"];`

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I guess it doesn't. In my first version I was adding an `NSExpressionDescription` for `evenOddExpression` and including that in `propertiesToFetch`. That **does** require a dictionary result since the expression doesn't exist on the entity. But then I dropped it from `propertiesToFetch` and forgot that I didn't need the dictionary result type any more. Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of math in a predicate is not supported.

Workaround:

Create a boolean computed property `isEven` in the `NSManagedObject` subclass

```
- (BOOL)isEven
{
   return self.street % 2 == 0
}
```

and use the format `isEven == TRUE` or `isEven == FALSE` in the predicate.

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isEven == TRUE)"];
```

Comment: Thanks Vardian for your help.

Comment: Not true. See my answer. :)