# Using modulo operator in NSPredicate doesn't work

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, nspredicate

While using Core Data I need to select some records from an entity, between two fixed rank and where the rank is equal to a certain value modulo 128.

To do that I tried to use what first came to my mind, which is using a predicate like:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(rank >= 17) AND (rank <= 12319) AND ((rank % 128) == 29)")
```

But that does not work. I get an error message like the one below when running the program.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(rank >= 17) AND (rank <= 12319) AND ((rank % 128) == 29)"'
```

Thinking the percent sign (modulo) may be causing trouble I changed it to %%, but it is the same.

I know the part related to the modulo checking is the one causing problems.

What's the way to go?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605430/how-to-fetch-even-and-odd-values-from-core-data-using-predicate

Comment: OK thanks. This is actually exactly what I was doing, while hoping for a simpler answer, but as you mention it seems to be the way to go. I will continue to investigate in this direction then.

Answer (score 0):

The linked answer explains how you'd do this. As for **why** you need to do it that way, it's because `NSPredicate` format strings are a combination of string matching with a handful of mathematical comparisons, but don't directly support *performing calculations* as part of the predicate. So your `>=` and `<=` comparisons are fine, but modulus is not directly supported. `NSExpression` is more convoluted but extends the capabilities to include many more options.

You may find it useful to check out Apple's [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html) for more detail.