# Is there a way to use a computed property with a parameter in Core Data?

Tags: swift, core-data, database-design, nsmanagedobject, transient

This might be a weird question because I don't fully understand how transient and the new derived properties work in Core Data.
So imagine I have a `RegularClass` entity, which stores any class that repeats over time. A class can repeat for example every third day or every one week. This is how it looks in the data model:

[image: data model for RegularClass]

(a `RegularClass` belongs to a `Schedule` entity, which in turn belongs to a `Course` entity)

Now, if our class repeats every third day, we store the number 3 in the `frequency` property, and a string `"days"` in `unit` property, which is then converted to an enum in Swift. A `Schedule`, which every `RegularClass` belongs to, has a `startDate` property.

To check if a class happens at a given date, I came up with nothing better than calculating the difference in specified `unit` between the `startDate` and the given date, then taking a remainder between the difference and frequency, and if it's 0, than it's the date in which a class can occur.

```
var differenceComponent: Calendar.Component {
    switch unitType {
    case .weeks:
        return .weekOfYear
    case .days:
        return .day
    }
}

func getDifferenceFromDateComponents(_ dateComponents: DateComponents) -> Int? {
    switch unitType {
    case .weeks:
        return dateComponents.weekOfYear
    case .days:
        return dateComponents.day
    }
}

func dateIsInActiveState(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
    if let startDate = schedule?.startDate {
        let comps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([differenceComponent], from: startDate, to: date)
        if let difference = getDifferenceFromDateComponents(comps) {
            let remainder = Int64(difference) % frequency // that is the key!
            return remainder == 0
        }
    }
    return false
}

func containsDate(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
    if dateIsInActiveState(date) {
        if unitType == .days {
            return true
        }

        let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: date)
        return (weekdays?.allObjects as? [Weekday])?.contains(where: { $0.number == weekday }) ?? false
    }

    return false
}
```

Now, the thing is that this code works perfectly for courses that I've already got from a fetch request. But is there a way to pass a date parameter in a `NSPredicate` to calculate this while request happens? Or do I have to fetch all the courses and then filter them out manually?

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36606137/978300 suggests you could do the mod in a predicate, so maybe you could store all your start dates and frequencies as days then search?

Comment: @Giles I thought about it, but the problem is I might not have an end date, so it's going to be an infinite amount of dates that I need to store in the database.

Comment: I think that if you store your start date as days-from-day-zero, and you know your search date as days-from-day-zero, you should be able to do the search in a predicate with no extra storage days. search - start mod repeat

Comment: @Giles Hm, that's a good point! Although I also have weeks here, so this means that I also need to store weeks-from-day-zero. And I need to keep a `startDate` as a `Date` type so I don't have to convert amount of days to a date every time I need it. So I have to denormalize the table by adding two new fields, `startDays` and `startWeeks`, and calculate using your method. Not the best solution because of denormalization, but I guess that's the only way. Thank you! If you want, you can post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Perhaps you can just do it all as day calculations - e.g. the repeat cycle is simply 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue you could store your data as scalar types and then do simple arithmetic in your predicate. Rather than dates, use integers with a days-from-day-zero figure (or whatever minimum unit of time is necessary for these calculations). Store your repeat cycle as number-of-days.

Then you can use the calculation `((searchDate - startDate) mod repeatCycle) == 0` in your predicate to find matching classes.

As you have suggested, it might be sensible to denormalise your data for different search cases.